# New tab in browser (Lightning Service Console App)

Tags: lightning-web-components, service-cloud-console, tab, navigationmixin.navigate

We have an application that pulls URLs from configuration and creates buttons for such user defined URLs. Because we are in a console navigation environment, every time these URLs are internal, instead of opening a new browser tab, it creates a console sub-tab.

[image]

Initially I thought it was great, but noticed many of the pages are not optimized to finalize under a console tab (return URLs and redirects break the tab on finish) so now I'm wanting all pages to open in a new browser tab. Currently invoking a redirect NavigationMixin.Navigate which works fine for externally hosted pages. Is there a way to change this behavior for same domain pages? The premise is that I can't touch the destination pages at all, just the page with the buttons in the console.

```
redirectTile(){
    if(this.tileUrl){
        if (this.tilePageRegion==='New Tab'){ // open new tab
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__webPage',
                    attributes: {
                        url: this.tileUrl
                    }
                },
            );
        }else {
            location.href = this.tileUrl; //Same page replaces full page
        }  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want new browser tab, you should not really use `NavigationMixin` - it will simply add the url to current url as it takes it as partial url (bug). So, instead you can use window.open directly:

```
if (this.tilePageRegion === 'New Tab') {
    window.open(this.tileUrl, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: TY, worked as stated!  I'm not sure why I was confusing DOM containment for "document" and "window" (only query LWC restrictions) with other operations using those two objects. I was also misled by the LWC documentation on navigation and best practices because it states to use 'lightning/navigation' https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation

Comment: In Aura or LWC you have access to window and document, but only that they are secure versions and only limited methods on them are exposed - so you can use those exposed methods on secure window/document objects